# Running Geoserver from source does not include the extension

Tags: geoserver

It's pretty odd. From the documentation it is explained to use the following command

```
mvn install -DskipTests -P authkey
```

To install Geoserver with the extension `authkey`

Followed by

```
cd web/app
mvn jetty:run
```

I do not get the extension listed on the Geoserver status page and cannot add the authentication filter from the "Users, groups, ..." Menu

No matter if I use `authkey` profile or any other like `excel`, etc...

The compilation is always successful with no errors or hint and the build result even shows me it's included with "Authentication by URL..."

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything required to build from the web-app before running jetty to become the extension loaded/available?

Resources:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/quickstart/maven.html

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/maven-guide/index.html#building-extensions

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify the profile(s) you want when you run the webapp. It's been a while since I did this at the command line but I think that the following should work.

```
cd web/app
mvn clean jetty:run -Pauthkey
```